# shortening of url in address bar

Tags: javascript, redirect, short-url

I am new to html. Is it possible to have Short URL for apps? 
 for example:- instead of long url "www.abc.com\x\y\z\a" can we have "www.abc.com\r" in the user 's address bar. can we emulate this using javascript?

Comment: question is not clear. are you using something bout url shortening services?

Comment: No, you cannot "emulate" that with only `javascript`. You need some server side settings like [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)

Comment: @BijoyThangaraj means I don't want to let user see the lengthy pathname of file in url instead I want some short string in url

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `url rewriting`

read on [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

[**URL Rewriting for Beginners**](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could by creating a document at location `/r`and adding a Javascript to that document which simply does:

```
document.location.href = "/x/y/z/a";
```

But, for many reasons you shouldn't.

1. It's not a redirect (you can go back in you browser, so you are basically breaking your history)
2. You rely on Javascript
3. It will have a negative effect on SEO
4. It's slower
5. ...

You really should try to handle this at the server side of you application.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using Database which gets the long URL to the Short one, so its noting you can do on Clientside only using Javascript.